# Rails 2.3x: Delete cookie with [] in the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm trying to delete a cookie for a form field value. The Rails text_field helper adds [] to the name. i.e. name=user[name]

In this case the cookie has been created with a path. (path = '/login/')

When I attempt to delete the cookie

```
cookies.delete("user[name]")
```

the [] get URL-encoded by Rack.

I can set the cookie to nil like this:

```
response['set-cookie']='user[name]='
```

which clears the cookie, but only for the path '/login'. (no trailing slash) The trailing slash is required to avoid an IE8 bug that fails to store the cookie without the trailing slash.

How can I set the cookie from the response object directly and set the path at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish deleting the cookies doing the following:

```
response["Set-Cookie"] = 'user[name]=; path=/login/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT'
```

To remove a second cookie you can then do this:

```
response["Set-Cookie"] = [ response["Set-Cookie"], 'user[email]=; path=/login/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT' ].join("\n")
```

which is exactly how Rack (v1.1.3) does it.

Then, the spec that would confirm the first cookie was deleted looks like this:

```
it "should delete the cookie used to store the username form field" do
  post :login, @correct_form_params
  response["Set-Cookie"][0].should =~ /user\[username\]=;/
end
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else out there!